# Is $\{a+\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ } \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^l\}=\{\sqrt{n}(b-a) \text{ }\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^l\}=\mathbb{R}^l$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Fix $a \in \mathbb{R}^l$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is the set $E:=\{a+\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ s.t } h \in \mathbb{R}^l\}=\mathbb{R}^l$?

Is the set $D:=\{\sqrt{n}(b-a) \text{ s.t. } b\in \mathbb{R}^l\}=\mathbb{R}^l$?

My confusion arises from: if I consider any $e \in \mathbb{R}^l$ I can find $h \in \mathbb{R}^l$ such that $e=a+\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$; similarly, if I consider any $d\in \mathbb{R}^l$ I can find $b \in \mathbb{R}^l$ such that  $d=\sqrt{n}(b-a)$. How is this related to the equivalence of sets above?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: The mathematical phrase $$\{a+\tfrac{h}{\sqrt{n}} \text{ } \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^l\}$$ is ill-formed. Perhaps what is meant is the set $$\{a+\tfrac{h}{\sqrt{n}} \mid h \in \mathbb{R}^l\}.$$ Likewise for $\{\sqrt{n}(b-a) \text{ }\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^l\}$.

Comment: It's definitely not a topology question. Can you suggest a better tag?

Comment: I have edited the question following your suggestions. I'm  not sure about the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x \in \mathbb{R}^l$. Then take $h = \sqrt{n}(x-a)$. And the reverse idea for the other.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm confused on whether there are implications for the equivalence of the sets above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in both cases the LHS is obviously a subset of the RHS so the question is really: can every $x\in\mathbb R^l$ be written this way?

In order to answer that, solve a (relatively easy) system of equations.